# How do I earn the Johnny Three-hats hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, secret-hats

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [How do I earn the Johnny Three-hats hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat) *1 answer*

I recently earned a secret hat. Is there any way to tell *how* I earned this hat?

[image: Johnny Three-hats]

> ### marked as duplicate of itself by [The Guy with The Hat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/238586/the-guy-with-the-hat) Dec 20 at 20:28
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [edit this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/211710/edit) to explain how it is different or [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: ["One hat good, three hats better."](http://www.davewilsonphotography.com/wp-content/images/main/2013_10/Longhorn_Band-9515.jpg) ([source](http://www.davewilsonphotography.com/2013/10/30/one-hat-good-three-hats-better/))

Comment: What does Johnny-Only-has-one-hat think?

Comment: @random [Stop dissing the hats.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8K1fTZaR7w)

Comment: @random Who's "Johnny-Only-has-one-hat"? I thought I might have earned this hat from having 3 other hats, but there are others who have 3+ hats not including this one.

Comment: Captain Obvious to the rescue!

Comment: Luckily, this hat stack perfectly on my usual one, making it a Johnny Four-Hats for me :)

Comment: +1 for rollover edit :)

Comment: Duplicate of *itself*... I had no idea that was possible!

Comment: @RyanCarlson - it's very funny!

Comment: +1 for "duplicate of itself"

Comment: See.Even the Community moderator has a hat.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The Johnny Three-hats hat is earned by (spoiler below)

> earning three different hats on one site, within one day. Hats earned on different sites, on previous days or before the Winterbash started do not count.

Comment: So there is no way to tell how I earned a secret hat, except for guessing based on the name and was happening right before I earned the hat?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why would you decompile source code ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton shhh....  the use of decompiled source code is a secret ... (and so the tools to decompile it !)

Comment: @Mike how do i earn the chuck yeager then?

Comment: @AsshO.Le You gotta be quick...

Comment: @Hugo i really do not know what kind of quick, i tried from being first to like to being first to comment. hmm first to answer i guess?

Comment: @AsshO.Le, no, I tried being the first to answer... doesn't work. A co worker of mine just got it, the only peculiarity of his post was that his answer got more upvotes that the accepted answer (all question activity started after Winter Bash 2013).

Comment: It's not only that. I got the Johnny at the same time as my third post-start hat on the two sites where I have it, but I don't have it on some other sites where I've earned three hats.

Comment: Sadface :( still don't have Johnny, even though I've currently got 9 hats, 7 on SO after the start of winterbash.

Comment: I think you have to earn 3 hats in one day to get the Johnny three-hats hat

Comment: Indeed. Have it now.

Comment: @Bohemian If you look at the revision history, you will see that I was the person that added the spoiler.