# Winter Bash 2013: Secret Hats

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013, secret-hats

Even after you earn them, *secret hats* refuse to tell you what you earned them for:

[image]

What's the point of the hat, if it won't tell me how I earned it?

This seems like a bug: The description should change from "*this is a secret hat*" to some real description after you've earned it.

This question is the more general case of this one:

- [How do I earn the Johnny Three-hats hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat)

Comment: See, then you might tell people, and that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh Fair enough. Was just curious how I ended up with it!

Comment: `This question is the more general case of this one:

    How do I earn the Johnny Three-hats hat?`
I actually intended that question to be pretty much exactly like this one, but mine got edited to be more specific :\

Comment: Hats should be fun, getting a secret had and not knowing why isn't fun. Knowing why when no one else knows is fun. If people want to spoil their own fun with spoilers then let them

Comment: See: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/191655)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They're not really all that *secret* if we give it all away so easily, are they?

Here are some hints - if you can figure them out, you're on your way to some SECRET hats:

- ...then I took an arrow to the knee.
- Earned ten of the most meaningless points on the 'Net
- I live... AGAIN!
- He ain't no drag
- from JBM to JWH
- Humpty Dumpty, or perfect in every way?
- There are only so many people capable of putting together words that stir and move and sing.
- You look like an absolute idiot.
- You may have to go to Puerto Vallarta, break the law and then fight extradition to get over this one.
- Solve these riddles and it's yours

Comment: -1. Your riddles are too damn hard!

Comment: With googles help I understand the Puerto Vallarta one.. not sure on the exact criteria though

Comment: That one might be a tough hat to earn, @James.

Comment: @Shog9 FUS RO DAH?

Comment: I guess I know how to achieve the last one but I don't know how to make it possible.

Comment: Wait, I think I've figured it out... from a sockpuppet account, post a spam answer about Humpty Dumpty pulling a McAfee, which receives an upvote?

Comment: @Jamal Actually, when I read "Perfect in every way" I went to give a look at Jon Skeet profile.... but no hat for that.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have all riddles lined up with hats now.. :-D Not that we have a *name* yet for the 10th, but I am 90% certain how to earn that one now.

Comment: So, where are your solutions @Martijn?

Comment: @Shog9: How do you want me to communicate them? I'd rather not spoil the surprise for everyone else. I haven't got the 'how to earn' them down pat for all, but I know what hat goes with what riddle.

Comment: email works, @Martijn.

Comment: I keep seeing "FUS RO DAH" posted in comments or chats... I'm starting to wonder if commenting on this trend might lead to some new insight.

Comment: FUS RO DAH!!! Comments go flying....

Comment: I think I figured out the last one too. Am I right? ;)

Comment: I don't know... Are you?

Comment: @llmariKaronen That is a real riddle that is a clue for lighting the way... were you being sarcastic?

Comment: Ugh. These are hints? :(

Comment: What do you say when you figure something out?  That's my hint ;)

Comment: @Man "Holy crap, that's awesome!"

Comment: @Kit It's a word that starts with an 'E', and it has to do with a -o- -e-i-- it.

Comment: Well, I figured out the part with the dog relish already. It's the word that starts with an E...what is that, Eukanuba? Because I tried a bunch of words in chat already.

Comment: Omg, it's not *dog relish*! It's *Shog fetish*! No wonder I had a hard time with it.

Comment: EVERYONE has a "hard time" with... Wait, no, that's not right at all.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging Oh, I get it! It's *fox zenith*. Well, that's pretty specific to me, though. How did everyone else figure it out?