# I (Don't) See Your Point: How do I earn this unicorn hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, unicorns, secret-hats

[image: I See Your Point; this is a secret hat]

I earned this hat, [I See Your Point](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013), on Stack Overflow, but at the time it popped up (a few hours ago), I hadn't actually been doing anything on SO (or mSO) for some time prior to that. Nor did I get any reputation, upvotes, badges, or other obvious activity that would easily explain it.

This also seems to be a *very rare* hat...

Comment: Michael the unicorn hat is just stunning on the IPv6 forever symbol! No, I'm not just being a sycophant, fishing for hats. Unicorn hat looks like it was custom fit for your avatar! I'm very pleased with the rakish good looks and fit of the marauder hat on my babirussa piggy avatar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just got this hat without much activity on SO. Judging form [Gilles' idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/i-dont-see-your-point-how-do-i-earn-this-unicorn-hat#comment681771_211979), I checked my meta activity and found that someone just upvoted one of my comments, and now I have:

> **5 comments (on meta) with a score of 2 or more** since Winter Bash has started.

So this hat is like the meta equivalent of [Peanut Gallery](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/peanut-gallery). Given the unicorn look of the hat, and most of the people I see on the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) who have this hat are meta regulars, it proves Gilles point that earning this hat is a result of meta activity.

Comment: Gah, the secret is out!

Comment: @jmac If you are looking at this post, you are probably desperate for the answer, so just let it be.

Comment: I think he was trying to un-spoiler it.

Comment: @Antony, I'm offended by your dislike of squash (both the sport and the gourd) and highly recommend you put it back for the reasons Mr. Peanut explains.

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish We can always take the middle ground, right?

Comment: The hat is a lie!

Comment: So [my guess](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1684042#1684042) was correct.

Comment: Also note that you can do this on mSO and on the per-site metas for extra unicorn hats!

Comment: C'mon, public knowledge is too much for the power of *seekrets!*

Comment: @TravisJ the hat is real, it is not a lie, and don't offend the unicorns.

Comment: The hat is a cake!

Answer (score 7):

[You need to earn ten of the most meaningless points on the Internet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/winter-bash-2013-secret-hats/211750#211750). Possibly in a batched manner, I'm not sure.

Also, unicorns. Unicorns are important.

Answer (score 4):

No *other* activity? Nothing *out of the ordinary*? I guess I don't see your point because I see your *points*. ;)

But I wouldn't want to impose on the Grinch's sekrits.. There is good in him.

Answer (score 2):

I was sincerely hoping that the "Twilight Sparkle Unicorn Hat" would be automagically awarded to the creator of the original "[The quest for the winter unicorn of the bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash)" post.

Still nothing though.

I sincerely hope I don't have to upvote THAT post.... because I CANT upvote MY post... ^_^

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza me too? :)

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza You spelled "by" wrong.

Comment: But if we upvote your comments because you want that hat, it won't be that meaningless, would it? :)