# Can we get some hints for the 2015 secret hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, secret-hats

We're a week into Winter Bash 2015, and a lot of secret hats have been found. How do you get these secret hats for yourself? Well, figuring *that* out is half the fun! I mean, you *could* be boring and just cheat off [other people's work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats), but nuts to that, I say. There's nothing worse than a cheaty cheating cheater.

If you want to Do it Yourself (see what I did there?) but just need a little help (or you tried to cheat but nobody else had figured out the hat you're after yet), then what are your options? Why, read some <strike>cryptic</strike> helpful hints, of course!

(Note: the hints are being released in "packs" that go from harder to easier, and later ones may reference earlier ones, so it might be helpful to set your answer sort order to "oldest" while reading this.)

Comment: Is "hint pack 2" for more hats!? Or just more hints for the same hats?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox The answer is "Hats!"

Comment: @balpha :DDDD!!!

Comment: What on earth is Flip flop?

Comment: @Zizouz212 there's a hint for it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio No! It's not Black and Blue! It's not White and Gold! It was like, Brown and Purple thank you very much!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Hint pack 1:

- Solve these riddles and it's yours. ([Sound familiar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211750/))
- What's a better hint, the first word, or the second?
- Rejected hat name: "What Are You Still Doing Here?"
- What if Mjolnir were made of gold?
- Mostly a good guy, but not *always*.
- Not the admiral's most important work, but her most famous.
- Tahiti, 1791.
- It's actually just one [<strike>dress</strike>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress_(viral_phenomenon)) hat, which will become more obvious in better lighting.
- It's not garbage until it's served its purpose.
- It's important to know your history... in more ways than one.
- One not familiar with the meme might argue that a better name would be "They're Over 9000!"
- Turnabout is fair play.
- Why not just call it "7"?

**Please do *not* edit this or post theories/guesses here**. This answer should stay "clean" for others who just want to get hints and work things out on their own.

Comment: If you couldn't tell from the fact that this is "Hint pack 1," there will be at least a "Hint pack 2" down the line.

Comment: Are we to take from this there are 12 secret hats?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto you mean 13?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto well, *at least* 13.  A day ago you might have thought there were only 12.  Who's to say that more won't be revealed?

Comment: @Pearson these hints pertain to the 13 already-found hats. There're actually more hats. At least four I think.

Comment: @nicael You reminded me of Battlestar Galactica. 7 cylon models are known, the final 5 will be revealed :)

Comment: @nicael At this point it seems hard to believe that 4 more secret hats that nobody got so far exist, unless all of them are triggered by a certain date. Though 4 more would make some sense, since it would bring the total number of hats to the round 45 (I thought the secret hats would stop coming when the total reached 40, but I was wrong).

Comment: Well, now its over, 'fess up! (onion knight and Edward Edwards)

Comment: How did you accept your own answer?

Answer (score 15):

### Hint pack 2:

1. Archimedes
2. Onion Knight
3. It's Always 5 O'Clock Somewhere
4. Odinson
5. Sun Wukong
6. Amazing Grace
7. Edward Edwards
8. Flip Flop
9. Cleanup Crew
10. Flying Tiger
11. It's Over 9000!
12. Hairboat's Revenge
13. 007

The order here matches the order from [hint pack 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271567/).

**Please do *not* edit this or post theories/guesses here**. This answer should stay "clean" for others who just want to get hints and work things out on their own.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Is this list of secret hats complete, or could there be more? 2. Why aren't the question and answer posts community wiki? Personally, I don't see why you should be earning rep for them.

Comment: 1. The number of secret hats is itself a secret until the end of Winter Bash.  2. Using CW as a rep denial mechanism has always been a bit of an antipattern. Not awarding rep to one person for a post owned by multiple people makes sense on the surface, but taking rep out of the picture isn't the primary purpose of CW. And since these posts are explicitly designed to __not__ be edited, CW would be especially semantically wrong here.

Comment: Bang goes my chance of earning Sun Wukong, so close, and yet so far.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code in addition to what Pops said: Pops created the hat triggers and the hints; why *shouldn't* he get whatever benefits come with posting these hints?

Comment: Any reason this here is numbered list and the other is bulleted list? Was going to edit the other one to make it easier to track, but your "Please do not edit this" stopped me.

Comment: The first one was bulleted because I posted them in no particular order. This one is numbered to assist in indicating that I posted them in the same order as the order of hint pack 1.

Answer (score 12):

### Hint pack 3

This *includes* all of the contents of hint packs 1 and 2, so if you're late to the game and wanted just the harder hints first, start with the other answers!

**Archimedes**

[image: Archimedes hat]

- Solve these riddles and it's yours. ([Sound familiar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/winter-bash-2013-secret-hats/211750#211750))
- Running naked through the streets of Syracuse is strongly discouraged, and neither I nor Stack Exchange are responsible for the consequences if you choose to do so.

**Onion Knight**

[image: Onion Knight hat]

- What's a better hint, the first word, or the second?
- The first. It's the first. So, how do onions make you feel?

**It's Five O'Clock Somewhere**

[image: It's Five O'Clock Somewhere hat]

- Rejected hat name: "What Are You Still Doing Here?"
- Zoom in real close on this one.

**Odinson**

[image: Odinson hat]

- What if Mjolnir were made of gold?
- It'd look something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).

**Sun Wukong**

[image: Sun Wukong hat]

- Mostly a good guy, but not *always*.
- What's a place where a little bit of argument and controversy might be a good thing once in a while?

**Amazing Grace**

[image: Amazing Grace hat]

- Not the admiral's most important work, but her most famous.
- [image: The first literal computer bug.]

  (photo [from Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper#Anecdotes), in public domain)

**Edward Edwards**

[image: Edward Edwards hat]

- Tahiti, 1791.
- Why would the hat be named for Captain Edwards and not the more well-known [Captain Bligh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Bligh)?

**Flip Flop**

[image: Flip Flop hat (blue)]
[image: Flip Flop hat (white)]

- It's actually just one [<strike>dress</strike>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress_(viral_phenomenon)) hat, which will become more obvious in better lighting.
- Remember the first footnote in [the Winter Bash 2015 announcement blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/14/announcing-winter-bash-2015/).

**Cleanup Crew**

[image: Cleanup Crew hat]

- It's not garbage until it's served its purpose.
- How do you know when a comment has served its purpose, anyways?

**Flying Tiger**

[image: Flying Tiger hat]

- It's important to know your history... in more ways than one.
- Well, really just two ways. (What? Two *is* more than one.) Earth military history, mid-twentieth century; and Stack Exchange Winter Bash history, 2014.

**It's Over 9000!**

[image: It's Over 9000! hat]

- One not familiar with the meme might argue that a better name would be "They're Over 9000!"
- This hat can be earned with either quality or quantity (we prefer quality).

**Hairboat's Revenge**

[image: Hairboat's Revenge hat]

- Turnabout is fair play.
- Who ran [Winter Bash last year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/12/15/winter-bash-2014/), again?

**007**

[image: 007 hat]

- Why not just call it "7"?
- Each individual digit has to account for *something*.

**Please do not edit this or post theories/guesses here.** This answer should stay "clean" for others who just want to get hints and work things out on their own.

Comment: I see what you are doing here!  You just want a hat!!!!

Comment: Huh? I don't think this post gets me closer to any of the hats I don't already have. EDIT: oh, actually it does, I honestly didn't even see that until your comment prompted me to go look at the list.

Comment: So... where and how exactly are we supposed to share ideas and notes while figuring out the last two, now that every discussion on the [Winter Bash 2015 secret hats question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) was deleted and all "Let's work out how to get X secret hat" discussions [just get closed as a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271913/i-recently-earned-onion-knight-what-is-it?lq=1)? Seems no fun and virtually impossible if we're not allowed to collaborate `:-(`

Comment: @user568458 the [winter bash chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32836/davids-hat-store)

Comment: Oh, oh! I know! Onions inflame my joints! But...I get a hat for that?

Comment: @david sorry, but chat rooms are a rubbish tool for collaborative problem solving compared to SE. That one is just people repeating the same wild guesses that were disproved already and all the discussions on different hats are getting mixed up and crossing over each other. It was much better when we were actually allowed to share notes, list known examples and collaborate in a systematic way. "Is it downvotes" no, we found un-downvoted Qs weeks ago, "25 votes" no, same. Gahh...