# Winter Bash 2017 Hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2017

Here's the traditional Winter Bash hats post. Same as last year there are two (and only two) answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats.

> *Remember* there are no hats for guessing secret hat triggers, nor one for pinging SE employees.

Only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.
Please put secret hat triggers in a [spoiler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/278094).
If you'd like to discuss hats further and/or work towards identifying what their triggers are, please do so in the [Winter Bash chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69997/wb17).
*Note* comments are not meant for extended conversation, discussion etc of any hat, use the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69997/wb17) for that.

If there are regular hats that are not listed yet, please edit and add them. If you know more specific info about one of the hats (example: time zones), edit that in, a source would be preferable.

Here are some of the hats of previous Winter Bashes:
[Winter Bash 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/278094)
[Winter Bash 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/278094)
[Winter Bash 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/278094)

Because It's important to know your history... in more ways than one[.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271567/278094)

Comment: The hats are largely replays from prior years, based on the blog.

Comment: Might want to merge [these kinda posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288803/a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-2016-hats-are-named-after/288809#288809) into this main one as well.

Comment: Any idea for **Penguin hat**??

Comment: @NoopurDabhi - what do you mean, penguin hat?

Comment: @Mithrandir looks like an attempt to request a new hat for next winterbash.

Comment: Because this is one of the top hits for Winter Bash in 2018, you are probably now looking for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list

Answer (score 181):

## Secret Hats

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

**Ooh, Shiny!**

[image: Ooh, Shiny!]

> Flag a question for closing, cast a close, delete or reopen vote on a question. You don't have to be the last vote, and hammers work.

---

**Cosmic Brain**

[image: Cosmic Brain]

> Earn the Nice Answer badge. [Answer score of 10 or more]

---

**Galaxy Brain**

[image: Galaxy Brain]

> Earn the Good Answer badge. [Answer score of 25 or more]

---

**Universe Brain**

[image: Universe Brain]

> Earn the Great Answer badge. [Answer score of 100 or more]

---

**Rep Cap**

[image: Rep Cap]

> Well, this one is obvious - reach the reputation cap. Actually, it's enough to reach 200 rep even without hitting the rep cap.

---

**Mother of Dragons**

[image: Mother of Dragons]

> Procedure confirmed by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304919/284336):
>
> - Visit a site where you have never posted a question or answer before (even if it's been deleted).
> - Post a new question or answer during Winter Bash.
> - Get its score to at least 3.
> - Wait until the post is 3 days old.
> - The post cannot be deleted or community wiki, and if it's a question, it cannot be closed.

---

**Row Of Many Candles**

[image: Row Of Many Candles]

> Participate in a site (vote, post a question, post an answer, etc...) while it's 2017-12-20 (the last day of Hanukkah 2017) anywhere in the world. The hat was first triggered on 2017-12-19 10:00AM UTC.

---

**Some Kind Of Sun Thingy**

[image: Some Kind Of Sun Thingy]

> Participate in a site (vote, post a question, post an answer, etc...) while it's 2017-12-21 (the winter solstice) anywhere in the world. The hat was first triggered on 2017-12-20 10:00AM UTC.

---

**Red Hat With White Fur Trim**

[image: Red Hat With White Fur Trim]

> Participate in a site (vote, post a question, post an answer, etc...) while it's 2017-12-25 (Christmas day) anywhere in the world. The hat was first triggered on 2017-12-24 10:00AM UTC.

---

**Glasses With A Number On Top**

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top]

> Post a message in chat ±12h from Jan 1, 0:00 UTC that gets starred

---

Answer (score 107):

## Regular Hats

In celebration of the 6th anniversary of Winter Bash, some of the most beloved hats from previous Winter Bash are making a comeback. ([Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/))

The year and name of a hat's previous appearance are noted below each hat.

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

#### IDENTIFICATION DIVISION

[image: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION]

earn a silver badge

***from 2015:** Amazing Grace*

---

#### The Mad Hatter

[image: The Mad Hatter]

edit, or suggest an edit, 5 times in a single UTC day without commenting on the post

***from 2016:** The Hatter*

---

#### Foot of the Rainbow

[image: Foot of the Rainbow]

earn a gold badge

***from 2013:** I See Your Point*

---

#### Just Jesting

[image: Just Jesting]

post 10 comments that each earn an upvote

***from 2012:** Just Jesting*

---

#### Explorer

[image: Explorer]

post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

***from 2015:** Explorer*

---

### Too Cool

[image: Too Cool]

vote on seven questions or answers using the Android or iOS app

***from 2013:** Before It Was Cool*

---

### The Milliner

[image: The Milliner]

collect 11 hats

***from 2013:** The Milliner*

---

### Hero Of Time

[image: Hero Of Time]

ask a question when it is 7:00 (am or pm) in any time zone

***from the original Arqade's Hat Dash - 2011:** Link's Hat*

---

### Sherlock

[image: Sherlock]

ask a question and answer it yourself, with both posts getting a score of 3

***from 2016:** Elementary*

---

### Taco Tuesday Any Day

[image: Taco Tuesday Any Day]

post five answers that each get a score of at least 3

***from 2016:** Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it*

---

### Werewolf Hunter

[image: Werewolf Hunter]

edited 5 questions that were posted more than a year ago

***from 2014:** Werewolf Hunter*

---

### Like Clockwork

[image: Like Clockwork]

visit the site on 10 consecutive UTC days

***from 2016:** Like Clockwork*

---

### Think!

[image: Think!]

for 6 separate questions or answers, post gets edited by owner after you comment on it

***from 2013:** R-E-S-P-E-C-T*

---

### Fashionable

[image: Fashionable]

get over 9,000 combined total views on all questions that you asked during Winter Bash

***from 2016:** Trendsetter*

---

### Silencium

[image: Silencium]

answer a question that has never been commented on; your answer gets no comments and scores 7+

***from 2012:** I Do Say*

---

### Brunhilde

[image: Brunhilde]

earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

***from 2012:** Brunhilde*

---

### It’s-a me!

[image: It’s-a me!]

delete 6 comments from under posts (not your own) that were edited by their owners after you commented on them

***from the original Arqade's Hat Dash - 2011:** The Numismatic*

---

### This Is Fine

[image: This Is Fine]

delete 10 of your own comments posted in 2017 before the start of Winter Bash

***from 2016:** This Is Fine*

---

### I’ll Handle It

[image: I’ll Handle It]

vote to close a question, edit it from closed, vote to reopen

***from 2015:** Do it Yourself*

---

### Fascinator

[image: Fascinator]

use the site's search function on 3 consecutive UTC days

***from 2015:** Fan-hat-ic*

---

### Waffles

[image: Waffles]

answer a question scoring -3 or lower; the question eventually becomes 3+ and your answer becomes 5+

***from 2014:** Waffles*

---

### And YOU Get A Hat!

[image: And YOU Get A Hat!]

own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats

***from 2015:** Every! Body! Gets! A Hat!*

---

### Extra Toppings

[image: Extra Toppings]

post a competing answer to an existing accepted answer, reaching a score of at least +3

***from 2014:** 30 Minutes or Less*

Comment: The graphic for The Milliner looks enough like a [Minnie Pearl hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnie_Pearl#/media/File:Minnie_Pearl_hat.jpg), that they really ought to just go all the way and add a dangling price tag.

Comment: Note on "Hero of Time": it appears that the question must be positively scored in order to get the hat (eg. asking a junk question to get the hat will fail, and a question asked on a low-traffic site may take a while to get the hat).

Comment: @Mark That's true for all hats like that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer

Comment: @Mark the description is slightly ambiguous, "ask a question when it is 7:00 pm in any time zone".  Does that mean (as I think and hope it does) it doesn't have to be 7:00 in _your own_ timezone, as long as it's 7:00 in some timezone somewhere?  Or does it mean you can be in any timezone, but it has to be 7:00 in _your own_ timezone?

Comment: @JamesDunn The description used in years past was something along the lines of "ask when it is 7:00PM anywhere in the world." You are correct, it does not have to be 7:00 in your timezone.

Comment: Re: Hero of Time: It never says it has to be 7:00 *pm*. I asked [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/151588/42545) at 01:15 UTC and got the hat anyway, because it was 7:00am in UTC+5:45 (Nepal Standard Time). There is no corresponding UTC-6:15 AFAICT.

Comment: I’ll Handle It seems to be broken. What are the exact conditions for getting it?

Comment: What does "while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats" mean? That there are 20 different hats available? Why is that a condition, isn't it always the case?

Comment: @Fabian it means that all members of that site have **earned** at least 20 distinct hats *on that site*.

Comment: Does the Waffles hat have to be on a question that was posted during Winter Bash?

Comment: @AnandaMahto no the question can be from any time.