# The Secret of Secret Hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017, secret-hats

This sounds silly, but is there a way to find out how to obtain a secret hat? I have 2 secrets hats and I really want to know how I got them. All it says is the community I earned it on. Hopefully in the future, maybe once we obtain a secret hat, we'd be able to learn how we got it? I know once someone knows they'd most likely tell others how to get it? Is there already a way to check how you got a secret hat?

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304345/340456) contains the known triggers for secret hats, and the triggers will be revealed after Winter Bash.

Comment: If the triggers were given people could cheat instead of figuring the triggers out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole fun in secret hats is trying to reveal the secret, and this is a collaborative effort.

People guess the triggers in chat rooms, and when reaching a conclusion edit posts like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats/304345#304345), using spoiler markdown to not spoil the fun for others who still want to figure this out by themselves. (Even if they already got the hat)