# Is Where in the World? still awarded using Sklivvz's hardware RNG?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

The *Where in the World?* hat first appeared [in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) as a secret hat. In the [WB2016 wrap-up blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/09/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/), it was mentioned that the hat's awarded using [Sklivvz's then newly-built hardware RNG](http://sklivvz.com/posts/i-built-a-hardware-rng-for-christmas), a rather creative way to award the two hat forms randomly.

Just curious, is this year's *Where in the World?* also awarded the same way?

Comment: Why do all the easy to answer question get posted when I'm not here? I had already figured out that they  were using the same random generator We always got the same hat in 2016, 2017, and now 2019. I get the sun hat.

Comment: @David HAHA I realised it after getting the same hat in 2016 too. 2017? It didn't make an appearance [that year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is still awarded using Sklivvz's RNG.