# How many normal and secret hats have there been in past Winter Bashes?

Tags: discussion, statistics, winter-bash

Does Winter Bash have the same number of normal and secret hats every year? Is there a breakdown of normal and secret hats featured in past Winter Bashes?

Having such a list ***could*** perhaps allow us to estimate the number of secret hats in future Winter Bashes and approximate the number of secret hats yet to be found.

> **It's important to know your history ... in more ways than one.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Breakdown of hats featured in past Winter Bashes

| Winter Bash | Total hats | Normal hats | % normal hats | Secret hats | % secret hats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 35 | 27 | 77% | 8 | 23% |
| 2013 | 45 | 35 | 78% | 10 | 22% |
| 2014 | 38 | 30 | 79% | 8 | 21% |
| 2015 | 42 | 28 | 67% | 14* | 33% |
| 2016 | 42 | 28 | 67% | 14* | 33% |
| 2017 | 33 | 23 | 70% | 10 | 30% |
| 2018 | 30 | 21 | 70% | 9 | 30% |
| 2019 | 32 | 20 | 63% | 12* | 38% |
| 2020 | 42 | 25* | 60% | 17 | 40% |
| 2021 | 41 | 19 | 46% | 22 | 54% |
| 2022 | 48 | 21 | 44% | 27* | 56% |

---

#### Notes

* Counts the two versions of "Flip Flop" (2015), "Where in the World?" (2016, 2019 and 2020) and "Solstice" (2022) hats twice but a user is only able to [get one version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340842/is-where-in-the-world-still-awarded-using-sklivvzs-hardware-rng).

Comment: There appears to be disagreement about amount of secret hats this year, why?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars There's one more yet-to-be revealed secret hat, [per Catija in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62624573#62624573). (I didn't link the chat message in the above answer as there's probably no need for the hat count to have a source once WB ends.)

Comment: Oh, most likely on the New Year day, 1/1. Nice. :)

Comment: @Shadow Do you mean the _Glasses with a Number on Top_ which is listed in the regular hat list : "Post a question, answer, vote, or comment on New Year's Day" : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f-%ef%b8%8f

Comment: @XaC huh! *blush*. Well, eh, so no idea what other date might be meaningful until wb ends.

Comment: @XaC you never know.  Might be crafty to have a second one for extra effort on that day, especially since all the day ones have been simple thus far.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Could be an "award a bounty on the last day of Winter Bash" hat.

Answer (score 0):

As secret hats are not revealed if not won, we will never be sure about the actual number of hats, we can only go by the hats that have been acknowledged.

And as each WB has a different team, see [the (accepted) answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384857/289821) by Catija here, it will always be a guess how many hats there are and will be in any new edition.

Comment: There's always been confirmation whether all secret hats have been awarded after WB ends and can be confirmed by the `/stats` page released after WB. In every WB thus far, all secret hats have been awarded including last year's. [Catija's answer is inaccurate regarding that point.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62590412#62590412)