# Winter / Summer Bash 2022 Hat List ☃️ ️

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2022

[Winter / Summer Bash 2022](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) has started and the hats are listed below.

As always, there are only two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats. The secret hat list will be updated as we learn them.

*Please, only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.* Winter Bash is a fun event, so secret hat triggers should be put behind spoilers (use the `>!` markup) in order to not to spoil the fun for those users who want to discover the triggers themselves.

If you'd like to discuss Winter / Summer Bash, hats or just have a question about it please come over to the [Winter / Summer Bash 2022 (c)hatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141302/winter-summer-bash-2022). Even better, check the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/295232) first.

Please keep the comments here clean. As always, comments are not meant for discussion, conversation, "I just got hat X", etc. use the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141302/winter-summer-bash-2022) for that (comments may be cleaned up without further notice).

Here are the hats from previous years:

- [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List 😷 🎓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999)
- [Winter Bash 2020 hat list 👒 🎩](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915)
- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339891)
- [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838)
- [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340)
- [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271)
- [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789)
- [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170)
- [Winter Bash 2013 Secret Hats](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)

Comment: We could check the [person with the most hats](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/28994/cdjb?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) to find new hats: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ajrn.png

Answer (score 109, accepted):

## Secret hats for Winter / Summer Bash 2022

> **Do NOT use this post to guess or discuss triggers for secret hats, even if you think you know them. Edit this post with a secret hat trigger only if it was verified by staff, linking to the verification.**

---

#### Over 9000!

[image]

> Start any [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question of score two or greater on any network Meta site (score eight or greater on MSO or MSE) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62609318))

---

#### Collection Complete

[image]

> Another user saves one of your posts ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62575431#62575431))

> **Note:** Design of this hat was modified during WB. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384765/this-years-winter-bash-violates-the-geneva-conventions-no-really) for more information.

---

#### Not Found

[image]

> Visit the /404 page for an SE site ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62573482#62573482))

---

#### Heads up!

[image]

> Raise a helpful flag ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62571008#62571008))

---

#### Back In My Day

[image]

> Upvote a question over 5 years old ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62581699#62581699))

---

#### X Marks the Spot

[image]

> Get three other secret hats on one site ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62570982#62570982))

---

#### Chatterbox

[image]

> Send 5 distinct blocks of messages in one room in one day ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62585082#62585082))

---

#### Flagging

[image]

> 9 flags marked as helpful in your most recent 10 flags on unique question pages ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62620616#62620616))

---

#### Unflagging

[image]

> 23 flags marked as helpful in your most recent 25 flags on unique question pages ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62620616#62620616))

---

#### Everything Everywhere All At Once

[image]

> Upvote 10 answers to the same question ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62589964#62589964))

---

#### Emperor's New Hat

[image]

---

#### This Is The Way

[image]

> Ask a question that is upvoted, not closed and gets an answer ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62602657#62602657))

---

#### Thomas Mensah

[image]

> Complete 3 close reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 10 on Stack Overflow.) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62628795#62628795))

---

#### Albert Einstein

[image]

> Complete 3 suggested edits reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 10 on Stack Overflow.) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62628795#62628795))

---

#### Verified

[image]

> Post 8 chat room messages with a star ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62586004#62586004))

---

#### I'm Okay...

[image]

> Answer a bountied question (during the bounty period but not necessarily during WB) but don't receive the bounty, and have a positive score ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62577795#62577795))

---

#### Mario Molina

[image]

> Complete 3 reopen reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 10 on Stack Overflow.) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62628795#62628795))

---

#### Running Up That Hill

[image]

> Delete 50 comments older than 6 months ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62707652#62707652))

---

#### Defender of the Unicorn

[image]

> 1. Post a question on Meta Stack Exchange with a [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash) tag that later receives a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62584186#62584186))
>  
>  2. [Check in on Sparkles the Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385137/lets-check-in-on-sparkles-the-unicorn) and succeeded in guiding her back home ([hat award page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ1Dm.png))
>  
>  *(The hat and its trigger remains unchanged from 2021.)*

---

#### Four Ayes

[image]

> Have a specific post upvoted at least once per day for four days with no downvotes in between ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62599271#62599271))

---

#### Shakuntala Devi

[image]

> Review at least one First Question post a day for 5 days. The days do not need to be consecutive. ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629314#62629314))

---

#### Hedy Lamarr

[image]

> Review at least one First Answer post a day for 5 days. The days do not need to be consecutive. ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629294#62629294))

---

#### Gregorio Y. Zara

[image]

> Review at least one Low Quality post a day for 5 days. The days do not need to be consecutive. ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629212#62629212))

---

#### Solstice (Sun) / Solstice (Moon)

[image] [image]

> Participate/do any action on the Winter Solstice (December 21, 2022) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62617091#62617091))
>  
>  *(This hat comes in two forms but you can only get one.)*

---

#### Yes, a Robot

[image]

> [Check in on Sparkles the Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385137/lets-check-in-on-sparkles-the-unicorn) but failed in guiding her back home ([hat award page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOwP.png))
>  
>  **Note:** This hat can be earned in conjunction with *Defender of the Unicorn*. You only need to fail the quiz to get it, even if you have already passed it previously.

---

#### Introverts Unite

[image]

> Participate/do any action on World Introvert Day (January 2, 2023) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62679488))

Comment: Given how bountied questions seem to be ChatGPT honeypots, I wonder whether fake answers are going to generate a lot of "I'm Okay..." hats?

Comment: I dispute the explanation of “Heads up!”.   I just got it (on Super User) without doing the action given in the spoiler.

Comment: @G-Man that was confirmed, so most likely one of your old flags was handled.

Comment: With "Chatterbox" what is meant by "5 distinct blocks of messages"?

Comment: The trigger for "Everything Everywhere All At Once" is unfortunate. Incentivizes users to go and upvote a bunch of crap, just to get the hat.

Comment: @wim depends. If you know some heavily active questions, it is not that hard to upvote good answers. Not saying that it's easy tho, so it could indeed favor some "lazy behavior" for sure.

Comment: @kissu No on-topic question has 10+ good answers that are each contributing something novel and useful

Comment: @wim possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvue.js%5D+views%3A0). Huge framework, various versions, possible helpers/packages, vanilla JS solutions, with or without TS, more or less explicit examples, more detailed use-cases, pro/cons, API changes, differents bundler configurations, etc... The list can go on, 10 is feasible.

Comment: @wim It seems the easiest way to vote for 10 answers and not to break anything is to vote for Show off your hats! answers here on Meta.

Comment: @tripleee and everyone: please don't use comments here for guessing triggers, there are dedicated chat rooms for that. Let's keep things organized without making extra work for the mods.

Comment: Nodoby has found "Emperor's New Hat" ???

Comment: @Excorpion no one has guessed and posted the criterion.   Many people have gotten hats and not known why.

Comment: @TymaGaidash staff do know the triggers. However, they won't reveal them as the intent for the secret hats is for the community to discover the triggers. The way the description for those hats is added is by asking a staff member (usually Catija) [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141302/winter-summer-bash-2022) to confirm if the guess is correct.

Comment: I don't get how the "do at least one review for 5 days" spreading out over 5 days is better for the system/community than having it all done on one day. Was it only done like that to make it trickier to get and get more days of engagement?

Comment: @starball it is an excellent way to form a behavioral routine.  There is every likelihood that reviewers will not stop after doing the minimum since the next review is auto-loaded.  We need to "trick" users into being reviewers as much as possible.

Comment: @user692942 when you send several messages in a row without someone else saying something in between, that's one "block".

Comment: Does the lack of them now mean we will not get the spoilers for Emperor's New Hat and Running Up That Hill? Or do we still stand a chance?

Comment: **Running Up That Hill**?

Comment: The triggers for those last two were revealed in a chatroom, so not easy to get your hands on in a future year.

Comment: [Emperor trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTel0.jpg) and [Running trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAbA5.jpg) both almost had verification from mods.

Comment: Its actually 8,000 according to the original manga source material. 9000 was a bad dub

Answer (score 38):

## Regular hats for Winter / Summer Bash 2022

---

#### You Got Splunk!

[image]

Ask or answer a question with a tag that includes the string "data" and have a score of at least 1 on the post

---

#### Mmm, Cookies!

[image]

View the cookie settings modal

---

#### Sufganiyot

[image]

Post a question, answer, vote, or comment during Hanukkah (Dec 18-26)

---

#### Miranda

[image]

Suggest one or more edits that get approved

---

#### Rules Lawyer

[image]

Review the Stack Exchange Terms of Service or Code of Conduct pages

---

#### Cakewalk

[image]

Post a question, answer, vote, or comment on National Cupcake Day, Dec 15

---

#### Behind the Curtain

[image]

View the profile of a staff member

---

#### Tourist

[image]

Take the tour and get the Informed badge

---

#### A Penny Saved...

[image]

Save a post

> **Note:** Design of this hat was modified during WB. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384765/this-years-winter-bash-violates-the-geneva-conventions-no-really) for more information.

---

#### Lifesaver

[image]

"Create new list" in Saves

> **Note:** Design of this hat was modified during WB. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384765/this-years-winter-bash-violates-the-geneva-conventions-no-really) for more information.

---

#### I Voted

[image]

Vote on any post

---

#### 2cool4skool

[image]

Try High Contrast or Dark Mode (Stack Overflow only)

---

#### Hat Your Service

[image]

Write a well-received answer to a question from a "New contributor"

---

#### Glasses with a Number on Top

[image]

Post a question, answer, vote, or comment on New Year's Day

---

#### 11 Will Save The Day

[image]

Collect 11 hats on a single site

---

#### Maverick

[image]

Watch or ignore a tag

---

#### The Explorer

[image]

Write a well-received first question

---

#### Hey, Listen!

[image]

1. Edit a closed question from a "New contributor" that gets reopened
2. Choose "Edit post" for any posts marked as closed in the Stack Overflow "Staging Ground" and publish the question

---

#### Squared Away

[image]

Post 4 answers on 4 separate sites during WinterBash

---

#### Cubed Away

[image]

Post 4 questions and 4 answers on 4 separate sites during WinterBash

---

#### K-Pop Light Stick

[image]

Have an answer that reaches a score of 100 during Winter Bash (earn the Great Answer badge).

Comment: *Running Up That Hill* was featured in [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/05/the-winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-cafe-is-now-closed/).