# The Tourist hat trigger description is incomplete

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022, informed-badge

The Tourist hat description states:

[image]

Yet apparently reading the Tour badge is not enough to get the Tourist hat if you already have the Informed badge. This was confirmed by staff member Catija in a [chat post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62581707#62581707).

Since apparently users are still asking why they didn't get the hat, can we please fix the description to "Take the tour and earn the Informed badge" to avoid further confusion?

Comment: This has been amended in the [hats list thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/).

Comment: You have radically changed this to something else. The lacking description isn't a bug, people are expected to click the "more info" button and read a bit more if they want to get the hat.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars oh, but the point is that I didn't realize at all that there was a "more info" in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The description is not incomplete, you're just looking at the short description.

Every hat has both a long and short description. The short one is designed to look pretty in the Winter/Summer Bash UI and give most of the necessary info while the long description is where we opine about the caveats and specifics required for the hat.

[image: Long description for the Tourist hat reads "Visit the Tour page and view the entire thing (earn the Informed badge)."]

So, don't forget to check out those long descriptions when trying to troubleshoot why you're not getting a hat!

Comment: So users who already have *Informed* badge can't unlock this hat?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that the descriptions where indeed different.

Comment: @Himanshu On that site. I have it because I haven't looked at the tours on every site I'm a member of.