# Phrasing of "Squared Away" hat not clear

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, wording, winter-bash-2022

The Squared Away hat's description is (without clicking on it):

> Post 4 answers on 4 separate sites during Winter Bash

Which is unclear for many users, I came across 3 users asking in chat that why they didn't receive the hat, and we looked into their profile and realized that they think it's for 1 answer per site.

I had the same thought in the beginning as well. Could we rephrase it as something along the lines of:

> Post 4 answers *per site* on 4 separate sites during Winter Bash

Or using "each":

> Post 4 answers on 4 separate sites each during Winter Bash

Or, maybe rephrase it as something even more clear.

Comment: Should 4 questions and 4 answers be in the same site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Congrats, you fell for the same trick as I did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384761/the-tourist-hat-trigger-description-is-incomplete). Finally, I am not alone.

Jokes aside, the issue is that some of the hats have confusing ***short*** descriptions.
But if you check the long version that you get in the pop-up panel, you will see that it is indeed much more precise.

> Post 4 (positive, non-deleted) answers on 4 separate sites (**16 answers total**) during Winter Bash.

Considering that the Tourist hat's short version description was not changed, I fear that this one won't too.

Comment: A simple "each" would have resolved the issue.