# This year's Winter Bash violates the Geneva Conventions (no, really)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, legal, winter-bash-2022

I know the title of this post sounds like a bit of an exaggeration - but it's not; the ['Lifesaver' hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F-%EF%B8%8F/384708#384708) awarded in this year's bash which includes the red cross emblem violates Article 53 of the Geneva Conventions for the Protection of War Victims of 12 August 1949, which states:

> The use by individuals, societies, firms or companies either public or
> private, other than those entitled thereto under the present
> Convention, of the emblem or the designation “Red Cross” or “Geneva
> Cross”, or any sign or designation constituting an imitation thereof,
> whatever the object of such use, and irrespective of the date of its
> adoption, shall be prohibited at all times.

[This publication](https://www.redcross.org.uk/-/media/documents/about-us/british-red-cross---recognise-this-symbol-(2).pdf?la=en&hash=85D7331BBA32F02BFB514F57ADA8C247507E8A63) from the British Red Cross gives a brief explanation for why this is the case:

> If asked, many people in the UK would probably say that the red cross
> is a first aid or medical sign.
>
> In fact, first and foremost, the red cross emblem is a special sign of
> neutrality and protection in armed conflict. It is used to safeguard
> the wounded and sick and those who care for them. As such, the primary
> users are the medical services of the armed forces. The emblem shows
> that a person or object is protected under the 1949 Geneva Conventions
> (international humanitarian law).
>
> The secondary purpose of the emblem is to indicate that the person or
> object on which it is displayed is connected with the International
> Red Cross and Red Crescent Movement, which includes the British Red
> Cross.
>
> The emblem must be completely trusted to signify neutrality and
> protection, which is why its use is restricted by international and
> national law. If the red cross emblem or similar signs are used for
> other purposes, no matter how beneficial or inconsequential they may
> seem, the special significance of the emblem will be diminished.

This article has been widely implemented into national law - for example [in the UK](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/5-6/52/section/6) and [in the USA](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/706). The latter of these sets the penalty for use of the emblem by any person or corporation other than the American Red Cross or the armed forces as a fine, or imprisonment for a term of up to six months, or both.

This occasionally comes to media attention when video games change the symbol on their health packs, usually after receiving a strongly worded letter from the International Committee of the Red Cross.

I suggest altering the current colour of the cross on the Lifesaver hat from red, or altering the symbol to one not protected under international law.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars - I'm not sure this is the place to be challenging the Geneva Convention itself ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin of course, just had some steam to let out, it really annoys me, lol.

Comment: btw, it's not just the red cross on white, it's also the white cross on red. Both are against the Geneva Convention.

Comment: @Tetsujin so red cross on yellow background is allowed?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars - it's all right there in the UK link above.

Comment: Well... that's uncomfortable. Thanks for bringing this to our attention, we'll get right on fixing it. :)

Comment: @Catija - I wonder whether this may affect Collection Complete too...

Comment: @Tetsujin We're changing all three. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin The inverted Red Cross is the Swiss flag (and vice versa), why would using the Swiss flag be against Geneva conventions? Isn't using the white cross on red to indicate a medical sign simply wrong? See for example [here](https://pssjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1754-9493-7-13) for a bit of context.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - read the UK Law page, linked above, but here it is again for convenience… https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/5-6/52/section/6 Note: Geneva is in Switzerland, famously neutral ;))

Comment: Huh, so, as a Swiss in England, when I want to celebrate my national day, I can't break out the Swiss flag? Who knew.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - I think you're being rather over-literal. tbh, if you waved it on St George's Day, I doubt anyone would spot the difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not trying to be difficult, but as a Swiss, I wasn't aware that there are rules about me being not allowed to wave my own flag.

Comment: This is my favorite WinterBash bug report ever.

Comment: This may be my favorite bug report ever

Comment: ✌️ https://youtu.be/sh163n1lJ4M

Comment: They weren't the only ones. Among Us [was forced to change it too](https://imgur.com/jb9EkZo.png) [(source)](https://twitter.com/AmongUsGame/status/1620877346348879873?cxt=HHwWgsDS2frWwf4sAAAA).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all, thank you so much for bringing this to our attention. It's not uncommon for us to need to do a quick redesign of a hat that we release but never for such a serious reason.

We certainly didn't make this decision in a deliberate attempt to damage the reputation of the Red Cross - we just honestly weren't aware that this was a concern and based our designs on common real-world hats for lifeguards and nurses... the super hero one was purely us iterating on a theme.

To address this, we've re-released the hats in a color I hope we can all enjoy - pink!

I am personally more a fan of green but I may have offhandedly said "Just make them all pink. " and that's what we did.

Special credit goes to designer [scoso](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1139864/scoso) for the quick redesign and [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) for the build.

Comment: I hereby protest. You said pink, but they are kinda.. white right now :P

Comment: I'm kinda glad y'all went with pink, as someone who lives in the US green just signals to me "marijuana/CBD is sold here" which probably isn't the hat's intended meaning

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest green - that's what UK & EU Pharmacies [drug stores] use.

Rx seems to be mainly US & may not be recognised in other territories.

> Signs of authority
>
> Nowadays pharmacies display the green cross outside their shops. The green cross was first introduced as a pharmaceutical sign in continental Europe in the early 20th century as a replacement for the red cross, which was adopted by the International Red Cross in 1863. The green cross was not used in Britain until 1984, when the Royal Pharmaceutical Society of Great Britain chose it as the standard symbol for pharmacy. The society stipulated that it should be produced in a specified shade of green, or in black and white, and that the word ‘pharmacy’ or ‘pharmacist’ should appear with it.

Source: **[The origins and meanings of pharmacy symbols](https://wellcomecollection.org/articles/We9Wqx4AAA5amD91)**

Comment: Green cross in the US is often a symbol for a marijuana dispensery which, well...

Comment: @squillman this fits, many programmers need something like that due to stress. :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Yeah that was more of a "take that for what you will" :)  haha

Comment: [A sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacy#Symbols) of what it looks like. [A photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pharmacie,_Paris_2010.jpg) of one. [A much wider selection](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Pharmacy_signs).