# Chatterbox and Verified hats considering the same room as if belonging to different SE sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I participated in [2022 Winter\Summer Bash Starring room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/141338/2022-winter-summer-bash-starring-room) in order to attain the Chatterbox and Verified secret hats (their [triggers are already confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384709/258356)).

I received both the hats as expected. But what's interesting is that while Chatterbox was awarded on Stack Overflow, Verified was awarded on Meta Stack Exchange.

How is this possible?

Comment: Chatterbox is definitely awarded on whichever site is set as your chat parent site. I noticed that after earning the hat on my original parent site, changing my parent site to a different one was enough to earn it on the other site.

Comment: They're implemented in two different ways, likely because one is reused from last year and one is new this year, so different devs built them differently - Chatterbox looks at the user's chat parent and Verified uses the chat room's parent site instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two hats are implemented differently, which is the crux of the situation. This is likely due to the fact that one is reused from a previous year and one was created this year.

Chat is also a strange place and it does things no one expects.

#### Basic chat "parenting" overview:

Feel free to skip ahead if you already understand this bit.

Anyway, to explain, you need to understand Chat a little bit. Chat has three "servers" (Taryn always corrects me that they're databases, not servers... for pure accuracy). The three are: Stack Overflow Chat, Meta Stack Exchange Chat, and Stack Exchange Chat.

- On SO chat and MSE chat, rooms are only parented to those two sites, respectively. There's no options to change chat parent and it's just default set to that site.
- On SE Chat, rooms can be parented to any of the 180 sites *including* SO and MSE. On top of that, rooms can be parented to Area 51 Discussions or to "Stack Exchange" generally - the latter are considered "unparented" chat rooms.

When creating a chat room on SE Chat (AKA chat.SE) the creator gets to choose which site to parent the room to. It's also possible to change which site a room is parented to.

Similarly, as a user, you can choose to parent your chat.SE profile to a specific site on the network. The system sets a default (I'm not actually sure how this is chosen) but you can override it by going to your chat profile and clicking "Change" next to the site icon.

#### OK... but what does it all mean?

Let's take a specific situation.

Geraldine is chatting in The Frying Pan, the main chat room for the Cooking site. As an avid Sci-fi & Fantasy user, her chat profile is parented to SFF. She just got a notification for a new hat - but on which site???

When awarding a hat, there's two options:

1. award the hat to the user based on the chat **room**'s parent.
2. award the hat to the user based on the chat **user profile**'s parent.

For a hat that follows the first method, Geraldine would get the hat on the Cooking site. This also means that it's possible to earn the hat on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Exchange by chatting in rooms on Chat.SE that are parented to those sites. If Geraldine was chatting in the Winter Bash chat room, which is parented to MSE, she would get the hat on MSE. The benefit to this implementation is that users can earn the hat on multiple sites without needing to know what a chat parent is simply by participating in different sites' chat rooms.

If the hat follows the second method, instead Geraldine earns the hat on SFF, even if she's never chatted in a SFF room. The perk of this method is that she can reparent her chat profile to various sites and get the hat on them all with no additional chatting required. But, as you might imagine, it can lead to some confusion, particularly if she's unaware of what a Chat parent is.

#### So what about Verified and Chatterbox?

Verified is the first case. It is awarded based on the site the chat room is parented on where you get the stars. It's a bit late to do testing, so I'm not sure whether it required all of the stars to be in that site's rooms or if any seven stars would award the hat on the site with the most stars... or what. But it's an interesting thought.

Chatterbox is the second case. It's awarded based on the user's chat parent.

#### The case in the question, specifically

So, to answer the specific question, the reason you earned Chatterbox on SO while earning Verified on MSE is that you earned stars while chatting in a room parented on MSE but your chat profile is parented to Stack Overflow:

[image: User's chat profile, showing that it is parented to Stack Overflow.]

I'm assuming you were participating in the Winter Bash chat room, which would qualify for this case.

Comment: I'm guessing the Verified hat would not be awarded if the criteria are met in a room that isn't parented to any site (e.g., Charcoal HQ)?