# Why do I not have the Talkative badge with 47 messages and several have stars?

Tags: support, chat, badges, chat-stars

I noticed a badge (Talkative) and it seemed to me I should have been awarded it. Especially, since I had been awarded a similar Hat (Verified) during Winter/Summer Bash 2022.

The talkative badge is documented as needing 10 or more messages and at least one of them having been starred.

I did some digging with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1697924/2065794/where-do-i-have-this-badge-network-wide), that confirms I have never been awarded it.

From the [reports of my recent chat activity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/556770?tab=recent), I compiled a list of all the rooms I've participated with 10 or more posts and 1 or more stars:

| Room | Server | Messages | Stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Winter / Summer Bash 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141302/winter-summer-bash-2022) | Chat.SE pointing to Meta.SE | 830 since 12/16/22 | 27 on 23 messages |
| [Winter/Summer Bash Starring room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/141338/winter-summer-bash-starring-room) | Chat.SE pointing to Meta.SE | 107 since 12/16/22 | 53 on 42 messages |
| [Risner’s Tiny Hut](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/141674/risners-tiny-hut) | Chat.SE using parents | 47 since 1/1/23 | 15 on 15 messages |
| [Risner's Magnificent Mansion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141400/risners-magnificent-mansion) | Chat.SE pointing to SO | 367 since 12/21/22 | 8 on 5 messages |
| [Winter Bash 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/141327/winter-bash-2022) | Chat.SE pointing to SO | 11 since 12/16/22 | 10 on 10 messages |

Per conversations with Catija and others, it seems that will only be awarded on chat profiles created on one of the following:

- Chat rooms made on chat.stackoverflow.com.
- Chat rooms made on chat.meta.stackexchange.com.
- Chat rooms made on chat.stackexchange.com chosing a non-meta primary site other than SO or Meta.SE.

### Does anyone know the SQL query it performs or know why do I not yet have talkative on any site?

Comment: FYI, you can see more of your activity by manually changing the page, e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/556770?tab=recent&page=3

Comment: Good to know, I guess I assumed only one page was the limit.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I'm leaning towards guessing that this relates to the chat server... the two rooms you mention are both on chat.se but the rooms you've been chatting in are parented to SO and MSE, which both have their own servers. It's quite likely that the system only looks at participation on those  two servers for those two sites... does that make sense? This is likely what @ShadowWizardChasingStars is getting at in his comment under his now-deleted answer.

Comment: I wrote up some info about the WB hats here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384887/chatterbox-and-verified-hats-considering-the-same-room-as-if-belonging-to-differ/385694#385694 It includes an overview of how the chat servers work. You can tell them apart by looking at the URLs - chat.stackoverflow.com vs chat.meta.stackexchange.com vs chat.stackexchange.com. :) Since I can't move rooms between servers, no - all I could do is reparent a room to an actual SE site but then you'd get the badge there and not on SO or MSE. :)

Comment: The URL for the Mansion is `https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141400/risners-magnificent-mansion` so it's a chat.SE room. :D and the WB room was also on chat.SE. :) I can't find the Tiny Hut to check.

Comment: @Catija yeah, I want to check it some more then I might edit and undelete the answer.

Comment: @JamesRisner Tiny Hut is also on chat.se. :) So if my guess is correct, and the badges only look for participation on the "local" chat server and not in rooms parented to that site on the chat.se server... then everything is behaving as expected. You'll need to hang out in a chat room on Stack Overflow chat.

Comment: @Catija Ok, after many more hours research, I think I've updated this with your theory of why it isn't working. If you could confirm I'm now understanding your theory, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Were you able to learn more? Is my edit more clear?

Comment: @JamesRisner not yet, I have to check other users see how other rooms were created, didn't get to it yet. Your edit is good, nice!

Comment: This became more interesting. I seem to have gotten the badge on rpg.stackexchange.com, without having any starred messages. At least, none I can see. Could one be deleted?

Comment: Hmm, the SEDE query has broken since I last used it. Does anyone know what changed?