# Earned Heads Up! hat on MSE without any helpful flags for a year

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2022

I just got the Heads Up! secret hat on Meta Stack Exchange without flagging anything for a year.

[image]

As mentioned on the [hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f-%ef%b8%8f/384709#384709), the trigger for the Heads Up! hat is:

> Raise a helpful flag ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62571008#62571008))

Yet, the last time I raised a helpful flag on MSE was in December 2021. As you can see below:

[image]

Is the specified trigger wrong? Or maybe I am not supposed to have this hat on MSE.

---

**Edit:**

I think the hat triggered because I reviewed on the "Close Votes" queue and voted to close; but, those aren't considered flags, are they?

If it's because of that close vote, maybe the trigger text should be:

> Raise a helpful flag or vote to close a question.

**Edit 2:**

@VLAZ mentioned in a comment:

> No, votes and flags are different. Also, once your account has the ability to post close votes, you cannot flag for closure.

So for sure this is a bug. Either wrong wording for the hat trigger, or, incorrect backend code cause me to get a hat I am not supposed to get.

Comment: Is a close vote a kind of flag?

Comment: @Boots Not sure.

Comment: @Boots no, votes and flags are different. Also, once your account has the ability to post close votes, you cannot flag for closure.

Comment: @VLAZ True, so it must be a bug.

Comment: Well pity we can't see when we got each hat, if we could I'd compare that to the times I made certain actions.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Exactly!

Comment: I also got the Heads up! hat on Stack Overflow, with my last helpful flag being raised in October, and my only action today there being a vote to close a question.

Comment: @Adinia Interesting.

Comment: As [I commented three days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-#comment1283811_384709), I got “Heads up!” (on Super User) even though my last flag there was nine months ago, and a quick spot check doesn’t show any old flags having been handled recently. … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. There’s no real point in putting the trigger in a spoiler block in the body of your question when you reveal it in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Fun fact: close votes are, in fact, implemented as flags even though pretty much nobody ever thinks of them that way. So, whoops.
>
>  I just deployed a change to exclude Close, Reopen, Recommend Closure, and Leave Closed flags from the hat trigger.

We're not going to revoke hats that have already been awarded, but going forward the hat will operate as intended. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Hats off to you for the quick response.  Literally.