# What is the origin of "It's important to know your history... in more ways than one"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

The hat lists of some years include the quote "It's important to know your history... in more ways than one", e.g. [Winter Bash 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%EF%B8%8F-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F):

> Provided that "It's important to know your history... in more ways than one"  again this year, here are the hats from prior years.

Where did this quote originate from?

Comment: [*Flying Tiger*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272038/468333)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote seems to have its *roots* in one of the [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/468333) in Winter Bash 2015.

> ## Flying Tiger
>
> [image: Flying Tiger]
>
> > Answer a question with a -3 score that later goes to +3, and your answer is +5. This is very similar to last year's [Red Baron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281812/468333).
>
> It's important to know your history... in more ways than one.

And from [Jance's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271243/468333) on [Is there a list of what each of the Winter Bash hats is named after?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270788/468333) (2015 edition):

> "Flying Tiger" is named after the 1st American Volunteer Group of the Chinese Air force, active between 1941-1942. They were famous for the distinct shark face nose art they painted on their planes.
> suspiciously like the hat.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Kulfy for pointing out it originated in 2015. I then went for a deeper dive and found additional background about this quote.

The quote ***first originated*** [as part of a "hints pack"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271566/can-we-get-some-hints-for-the-2015-secret-hats/272038#272038) by Pops, the community manager who ran Winter Bash 2015.

> **Flying Tiger**
>
> [image: Flying Tiger hat]
>
> - It's important to know your history... in more ways than one.
> - Well, really just two ways. (What? Two *is* more than one.) Earth military history, mid-twentieth century; and Stack Exchange Winter Bash history, 2014.

"Stack Exchange Winter Bash history, 2014" likely refers to the fact that there was another hat with the same trigger in 2014.

"Earth military history, mid-twentieth century" then leads us to the exact 2014 hat – Red Baron. [read below for the reason]

As [explained by Pops after the Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270788/is-there-a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-hats-is-named-after/272558#272558):

> In doing so, we made the hat harder to earn than Red Baron, and so we needed a name that was similar but better. Unfortunately, there aren't many pilots who have topped Manfred von Richthofen, by any measure. In World War II, Erich Hartmann became the top flying ace of all time, but he flew for Germany, and I didn't think that would make for a very good Winter Bash hat for obvious reasons. Eventually, I gave up on finding a strictly superior hat name and went for a lateral move, to something that was still in the same realm (military aviation) but not directly comparable.