# What hats are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I'm somewhat new to participating in Stack Overflow and just realized today that there are "hats". Because I wouldn't mind collecting a few ...

**Is there a list of all hats available and what I need to do in order to get them?**

Comment: I just got the Treasure Hunter hat! My holidays are now complete. (Oh yeah I also got some gold badge for something or the other....)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no longer relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh god, are we going to have to go back and close-flag *all* winter bash 2013, 2014. 2015 questions now to stop people answering them?

Comment: @JonW no, but due to the nature of this question I'm afraid other users might try and update it with "relevant" answers.

Comment: Related: *[Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271)*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, here is a full list of all the hats and what you must do to get them. (Except the secret ones obviously).

http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's with the secret hats?

Comment: @mplungjan Take a loot at this : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/?cb=1

Comment: I mean, last year we could hover to see how we got them but I get nothing for my Chuck Yaeger (Which I see you have too) or Three-Hat

Comment: Yeah same question here.

Comment: Aha! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat?rq=1

Comment: 2018: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sweet! Time to get some hats : )