# 20 hats but no The Milliner?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I have reached the twenty hat threshold! However, I have not been awarded with The Milliner. At first I thought this could just be a case of being impatient, so I waited, but it still hasn't arrived!

[image]

Does this have something to do with my 20th hat being a secret hat? Should I just suck it up and wait until I get my 21st hat?

Comment: Do you need 20 hats total or 20 on one site?

Comment: The text just says "Earn 20 hats"

Comment: Who wants that thing on their head?  How do you even WEAR it?!?  It doesn't go with anything I have, I'm gonna have to go to Macy's and buy some shoes now...

Comment: @johnnybones lol

Comment: We probably could have been clearer in the description, but there isn't a lot of space to go into depth in the hat descriptions (well, in this screenshot there is, but not on the winter bash homepage). All hat descriptions describe what you have to do to earn that hat *on any given site*. Even though you can wear hats anywhere, a lot of users don't have accounts on multiple sites, so it's structured to work in a single-site scenario.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to earn 20 hats, after the start of Winter Bash, *on a single site*. You then earn The Milliner hat on that site. (Which means you could earn it more than once...)

This is the same [way the Johnny Three-hats hat works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211713/189912).

Comment: I was just editing this into my answer, but you can have it. :P