# Make "this is a duplicate" notice unique

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

As I demonstrated on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat) question, it is possible to make a question look like it is a duplicate, when it actually isn't.

The notice

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [How do I earn the Johnny Three-hats hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat) *1 answer*

looks identical to an actual duplicate notice like the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).

I think all duplicate notices should be made unique, e.g. by changing the color of the background.

Comment: Perhaps the same color as the Bulletins.

Comment: @TravisJ Or maybe a bit lighter. Just enough for the difference to be noticeable.

Comment: 1) What motivation does someone have for editing a post to make it appear to be a duplicate when it is not?  2) Are people in fact doing so in a way that is harmful?

Comment: The [custom CSS I use](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nPT8g.jpg) makes this untrue for me. ;P One of the reasons I wrote my own modifications.

Comment: @Servy It's not only about harmful, but it makes it more clear that it is in fact a notice and not a quote, especially for new users.

Comment: @Servy what 3ventic said, but also someone with low rep could edit a cw post to link to their question.

Comment: @3ventic And tricking users into thinking something is official when it is in fact not would indeed be harmful, generally.  Of course, that is if people were actually doing that, and it wasn't being [fixed right away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212993/186381)

Comment: This post is a duplicate of me not caring.

Comment: @Tim I'm sorry, can you repeat that?

Comment: I said.... wait.... I see what you did there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 But I do not think such deliberate deception will last long. Unless you post or edit a question this way in a low-trafic tag, it will get revised/edited away by the community. (I certainly hope so.)

Comment: Or actually closed as a real duplicate, if it is in fact a valid duplicate target.

Comment: @Servy Yes, what goes around, comes around. +1

Comment: The fake notice on my 1k+ views question has lasted 20 minutes already.

Comment: @Ryan But this is Meta. I think we are aware.

Comment: @RyanCarlson Can't you edit it away yourself if it bothers you?

Comment: @Tim I was the one that put it there.

Answer (score 2):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Duplicate close notice trolling? Just edit it out.