# Will the secret of the secret hats be revealed after the end of Winter Bash 2013?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, secret-hats

I know the *secret* of the secret hats is the best part of it. But then we're going to lose all the hats anyway, including the secret ones, on January 4th (the end of Winter Bash).

I really wish the powers that be revealed the secret of the secret hats after the end of Winter Bash. Mainly for four reasons, but others are welcome to add more.

1. Everybody loves the hats, and thus would really want to know about them.
2. We can't let the devs walk away with this. They might even use the same secret for the hats next year! We want the devs to come up with something new to intrigue us the next time as well. (We still love you, devs.)
3. Since SE is a network of question-and-answer sites, and wondering about the meaning of hats *is* a question, certainly SE is also the best place to get the answer from!
4. A secret reason I'm not going to tell you!

So is there is a plan to reveal the secret of all the secret hats at least *after* the end of Winter Bash?

Comment: *"we're going to lose the all the hats"*, I believe the NHA (National Hat Association) has something to say about that: [*"I'll give you my hat when you pry it from my cold, dead hands"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_my_cold,_dead_hands)

Comment: Actually, that was my plan... tracking all the info and posting them after the bash ends. Also notice that we are getting distracted by the hats, but I suspect there is something going one the bash site also. Last year there was an unicorn, this year I don't know.

Comment: For the right amount of bribery could make your life easier *right now*... *wink* *wink*

Comment: +1 because I *reeeeeeeaaaaaally* want to know!

Comment: Since you welcomed me to, i added the most important 4th reason!

Comment: In the meantime, lots of clues [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211707/i-have-a-secret-hat), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/winter-bash-2013-secret-hats) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats).

Comment: Is there Easter egg page for retrieving hats

Comment: Related: *[Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271)*

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Maybe... If you're nice to us.

And... **[here it is](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)**!

Comment: 44 hats last year!  Not as many this year I think but there are some elusive hats out there this year.  Like the "Hairboat"  *That* looks like a great hat. ;)

Comment: One of my favorite parts of SE is the hats. So cool to see all of them revealed, and I hope the tradition continues this year!

Comment: Why is Abby so freaking *popular* lately? Weird.

Comment: Hairboat is hard to say many times fast.  I agree that the hats are awesome.

Comment: My favorite is the snorkel hat last.

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat.

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat

Comment: This isn't going to end well...

Comment: It's a silly way to get a meaningless hat... clearly, not enough to stop me.

Comment: SX let us honour Hairboat by spamming his posts! Hairboat bless our spams :D

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat

Comment: What can I say except to add "Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat"?

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat

Comment: This can't be true. `:o`

Comment: Is your inbox getting full yet?

Comment: I was told there would be boats?

Comment: It's a trap...!

Comment: Bear coat, bear coat, bear coat

Comment: Madness? No. This. Is. STACKEXCHANGE!

Comment: What does this hairboat and Bear coat mean?

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist to a new hat :(

Comment: Hairboat Hairboat Hairboat

Comment: Hairboat!  I just need the hat, I must admit.

Comment: Bah. Here I am sucking into the gamification like everyone else.

Comment: Hairboat? Hairboat!

Comment: (reverse "hairboat")

Comment: Hairboat, Hairboat. However, if Hairboat, you must Hairboat.

Comment: Too late to get a hat?  *runs off to check*

Comment: Hey, what is going on here? ;-p

Comment: I think that the Hairboat hat is pretty cool.

Comment: Hairboat hairboat hairboat

Comment: $.get('hairboat')

Comment: Hair........boat!

Comment: In few hours new year will come, hats off to old one!

Comment: cout << "hairboat";

Comment: `hats.add(:Hairboat)`

Comment: Yes! Now I get that Warm Welcome hat! Oh, wait...

Comment: Hairboat.....??

Comment: Somebody should LOCK the comments on this question.

Comment: select * from hats where name = 'Hairboat'

Comment: /* No comment */

Comment: I CAN HAZ HAIRBOAT?

Comment: Winter bash is cool.. \o/

Comment: hairboat? hairboat!

Comment: Winter?? Bash!!

Comment: Hi, I just came for the hat.

Comment: Abby Hairboat is suddenly so popular...

Comment: Look, having boats made of hair really doesn't work very well; they leak, and are very hard to make...

Comment: Hairboat anyone? :)

Comment: The comments here need cleaning up.

Comment: Hairboat hairboat hairboat