# 429 Too Many Requests error on winter bash site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash, server

After looking through the top 20 pages of the leader board on the winter bash, if I go to the next page I get this error:

> Too many requests. Wait 40 seconds before requesting this resource again.

After the timeout period, I can get through even fewer pages, around page 28, before I get that same error.

Now I'm just looking through the hats to find new secret hats, and then on to the next page. Why am I encountering this error?

Comment: "*Why am I encountering this error?*" - Practically everything on SO is rate-limited.

Comment: sure, but just browsing through the pages, I can hit it?

Answer (score 17):

Yep. We recently added a rate limit on those pages because several scrapers were hammering them. (I assume they also were looking for secret hats.) I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but we've learned the hard way to [rate limit everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/1438). Failing to do that tends to bite us at some point.

As in years past, secret hats are fairly quickly noticed and [posted to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats). That's what I'd watch if I were you.

Comment: It was me, I'm sorry. Apparently I've chosen not the best way to collect hats stats. (not sure if anybody else also did this, it's actually pretty stupid)

Comment: Thanks for taking care of the site(s) so that we all can still get to it.  And @nicael, don't feel too bad.  We've all done something like that at one point or another.

Comment: How would constantly scraping those sites help find new hats? You still wouldn't know how they were collected for secret hats, wouldn't you?