# Why didn't I get the Hairboat's revenge hat?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2015, secret-hats

According to the [secret hat trigger list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/1438):

> > Hairboat's Revenge is earned by commenting on one of [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson)'s posts, or by replying to one of his comments. It cannot be earned by doing this on a *per-site* meta, only on main sites and Meta.SE. This hat is in retaliation to one of last year's hats, which was the same except that it was targeted at [abby hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat).

So I left this comment:

> [Hey, @JonEricson! Gimme teh hatz, plz! <|;-))) – Father Christmas♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats#comment881047_270851)

It's been **over 4 hours** and I still [don't have the hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackexchange.com). What gives?

Comment: Lies. You do have a hat, it's just caching!

Comment: @nicael: Ugh. That was an accident.

Comment: An accident? What a convenient excuse! But hey, whatever floats your (⌐■_■) boat.

Comment: @FatherChristmas The revenge of the hair boat will be upon thee!

Comment: @FatherChristmas It's nice to see you with your own hat. You got it!

Comment: And.... enjoy your new secret hat Jon!

Comment: That's one nice hat!

Comment: @FatherChristmas Gimme my boat! ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)

Comment: I got nothing... 1 nautical noggin adornment please. ⛵

Comment: Looking for free boat here.

Comment: @FatherChristmas Why don't I have the hat on Academia.SE yet?? :(

Comment: I posted a comment on a post of yours, days ago on EL&U, I just went back to check and the comment was deleted, but I didn't get a second Hairboat hat as I expected. I've just posted two comments on EL&U and I was immediately awarded the hat. I've deleted both comments, and the hat is still safe in my warm hands, so to speak, but what happened with the first comment on EL&U. Was it too serious?

Comment: I am, unashamedly, trying to get another secret hat, but not the Hairboat one. I shall wait and see if my fiendish plan works....

Comment: @AustinHenley: Unfortunately, there's [no way to earn the hat on Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/7682/jon-ericson?tab=activity&sort=all).

Answer (score 19):

Ugh. *That's* what you decided to write?

In any case, the reason you didn't get the hat is that you have to:

> ping [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/father-christmas) who has changed his display name from Jon Ericson to "Father Christmas". `@JonEricson` no longer works on this site.

---

On a more serious note (and the real reason I wrote this Q&A), it's been interesting to see the sorts of comments people send when they want to get a hat. I've been deleting the obvious I'm-just-trying-to-get-a-hat comments, but there have been some interesting comments that have really tried to grapple with whatever it is the comment is attached to. I appreciate those.

For your edification, here is [a gist with all comments directed at me](https://gist.github.com/jericson/54b6829e260cc8ed80d3) during Winter Bash 2015. I have only included the text, creation date, deletion date and site of each comment. Other identifying details have not been included to protect the guilty. Not every comment earned a hat because:

- some sites don't earn hats for this,
- some users commented more than once, and
- some comments were deleted before the hat was earned.

I can be pretty sure that all of the hats awarded on Stack Overflow were deliberately obtained. There were two comments on Biblical Hermeneutics that seem uninterested in hats. One of them was responsible for building the very first black sail on any site.

The tally:

```
String        Count
------        -----
secret           32
hat             428
boat             60
revenge          37
abby             14
sorry            48
thank            50
comment         102
jonericson      122
fatherchristmas  32
@               240
⛵                4
                2
ybba              1
egnever           1
taob              1
tah               1
terces            1
```

---

In case you are concerned, all is forgiven:

[image]

Comment: Wait, that's (at least) 647 comments. I can only guess when you've got so much time to filter them out ;)

Comment: "secret" "boat" "revenge" "Abby"

Comment: "hat" - to balance this ^^

Comment: Merry Christmas, Father Chirstmas!

Comment: But what about comments that include "ybbA" ro ,"egnever" ,"taob" ,"tah" ,"terces"? Will you count those, too?

Comment: You're having fun with all the comments, right?

Comment: i just want the dahm hat

Comment: Ah, ok, so, because of this I have to write another nonsense comment...

Comment: Honestly, I am commenting only to get the hat but isn't there a typo here somewhere - *who as changed his display name*?

Comment: Umm.... are you aware that @Fat also pings you now? :-D

Comment: Thanks for compiling the gist. After a quick glance it seems quite entertaining, if utterly predicable.

Comment: I also just want the hat.

Comment: Doesn't deleting the comments with the sole intention of getting a hat just cause the user to comment again, thereby adding more comments to your inbox? (P.S. can i haz hat?)

Comment: @MikeAtNobeli: Perhaps. But that's a risk I'm willing to take.

Comment: You "boat" must "secret" be "revenge" staying "Abby" very "hat" busy.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Seems quite appropriate actually. Ever seen Santa's belly? :)

Comment: @FatherChristmas hat plz <3

Comment: @FatherChristmas What if we ping you during the night when you're asleep? Or do you have a script set up to delete the comments automatically? Or are you just planning to not sleep for a few weeks?

Comment: I'm confused, how do I earn this hat? You'll have to add some more clarification..

Comment: @MikeAtNobel: If a user gets the hat, and FatherChristmas deletes their hat earning comment, does the user still keep the hat? If so, the user isn't very likely to repost their comment.

Comment: Hats. Hats never change.

Comment: @FatherChristmas I'm also interested in how you would check comments when you're a sleep, because most likely the comment rate will be too high for you to keep up with when doing it al by hand. Also if you would be automatically deleting comments, there is the potential danger of deleting good comments?

Comment: Heard Father Christmas is giving away !!hats. Merry Christmas and thank you for the hat :)

Comment: Dear @FatherChristmas -- are you real?  - signed, Virginia

Comment: @Virginia: Yes I am. But are you?

Comment: I didn't know about that trigger list before, now I can find out why I got my blue hat :-)

Comment: Well I guess it goes to show the things people will do for these hats. You could probably interest a psychologist in the study of Winter Bash - how people's behavior during Winter Bash is different than their normal SE behavior

Comment: C'mon @FatherChristmas now you're just asking for it.

Comment: @FatherChristmas I'm not sure I understand all these hat related memes.

Comment: need the hat yes

Comment: This is fantastic.

Comment: Does wanting the hat make me a hat-hoarder?  This Winter Bash event is the highlight of my year.  Color me pathetic (but hopefully with a rakishly affixed chapeau!) :-)  Happy New Year @FatherChristmas !

Comment: @JonEricson Did hairboat also send you the *box of spiders* mentioned in last years blog?

Comment: @BhargavRao: It must have been intercepted at customs or something. Or, perhaps, I'll get an awful surprise when I open a package of "coffee". ;-)

Comment: Haha, do mention if there was any spider in that box when you open it. :P