# Flip Flop is missing some colours!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, winter-bash-2015

### **Warning! Spoilers!**

> First off, the Flip Flop hat is totally the wrong colours. According to the [Super Top Secret No CM person will see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/289845) post:

> *It's actually just one [<strike>dress</strike>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress_(viral_phenomenon)) hat, which will become more obvious in better lighting.*

> Now the colour choices are totally wrong. If Flip Flop is supposed to be modelled off the colours of the infamous dress, then there is a popular colour combination still missing. To the eyes of some people, it was not *Blue and Black* and it was not *White and Gold*. It was... *Purple and Brown!* For those of you who think I am ridiculously, there is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313033/flip-flop-hat-what-did-i-do#comment286257_313088) comment on Meta Stack Overflow that has 9 up votes. These people seem to support that the dress was really purple and brown.

> At least make it random rainbow coloured :)

Comment: What silly person would see it as *purple and brown*? It's clearly pink and green!

Comment: @Anko What nonsense!?!?! This dress is clearly Purple and Brown!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see the problem here. The <s>hat</s> dress is clearly grey and orange.

The hat should definitely look more like this:

[image: Hat Overflow]

Comment: Would dig that.